# How to validate multiple urls separated by commas using a regular expression in .net mvc 4

Tags: .net, regex, model-view-controller, annotations

I have tried the following Regex to validate multiple urls, but it is not working properly.

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Top Post Url")]
[DataType(DataType.Url)]
[RegularExpression(@"(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-          
9+&@#/%=~_|]", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Url")]

public string PostsUrl { get; set; }
```

Comment: What do you mean to say? What is your input that should match?

Comment: I want to input for a field, which can accept multiple urls with comma separated like this (https://www.google.com,https://www.facebook.com,docs.google.com,google.com)...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go for a single regex.
I don't know how to code in C# but I can provide pseudo code.

```
String urls = "url1,url2";
Regex validUrlRegex = /^(https?:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+$/;
Array urlsArray = urls.split(',');
Boolean allUrlsArevalid = true;
for(int i=0; i < urlsArray; i++) {
 if(!urls.match(validUrlRegex)) {
   allUrlsArevalid = false;
   break;
 }
}

print allUrlsArevalid;
```

If you're looking for single regex. Then

```
Regex validUrlRegex = "/((?:https?:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/";
Regex desiredRegex = validUrlRegex + "(?:(?:,)" + validUrlRegex + ")*";
urls.match(desiredRegex);
```

Explanation

This is a simplified format string

"{validUrlRegex}(?:(?:,){validUrlRegex})*"

`(?:)` is not non-capturing parenthesis. i.e. anything inside it won't be stored in the resulting array.

`(?:(?:,){validUrlRegex})*` this will match zero or more occurences of `,someUrl`.

Comment: just cross check your expression with this link : 

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page